# Tastypie api for multiple models

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two models

```
class LCUser(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(LCUser,primary_key=True)
    mobile_phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)

class UserProfileResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource): 
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'profile'
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
```

I want to setup the /profile/  endpoint such that CRUD operations manage all 5 fields.

1) Can I do that ?
2) Is it a good practice ? 
3) If not what would be my alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class LCUser(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(LCUser, primary_key=True)
    mobile_phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

class LCUserResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'lcuser'
        queryset = LCUser.objects.all()
        excludes = ('password',)

class UserProfileResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(LCUserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'profile'
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
```

Make sure to exclude the password, you don't want that getting read.

Comment: Ty for the answer. Can you explain if what tastypie does to manage this? And if I can get all fields in the table using `fields.ToManyField()`

Comment: I'd recommend you read the docs: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: `fields.ToManyField()` is for representing m2m relationships.

Comment: Can I show / use just one field of the resource that is being referenced. eg: the id or email field of the LCUser table ?

Comment: Yes, you can set `LCUserResource.Meta.fields = ['email']`

Comment: This is my result `{
  "address": "address",
  "mobile_phone": 11223344,
  "user": 1
    "email": "sridanu@yahoo.com",
    "resource_uri": "/lcuser/1/"
  },
}` How can I change it so I get `{
  "address": "address",
  "mobile_phone": 11223344,
  "user": 1.
  "`

Comment: Read this: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#resource-options-aka-meta